# middleware for serving static files doesn't work for dynamic routes

Tags: css, node.js, express

I have a simple Node/Express server that worked fine when I had the route as "/:world". The CSS file was found correctly.

But when I change the route to "/:world/:page"  it doesn't find the CSS file.

Why is that? It sounds very simple but i'm kinda new, any solution?

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request-promise');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/:world/:page', async (req, res) => {
 var world = req.params.world;
 var page = req.params.page;

 var worldInfo = await getWorldInfo(world);
 if (!worldInfo.world.world_information.players_online) {
    res.render('error.ejs');
 }else{

     var playersList = await getPlayersList(worldInfo, page);

     res.render('index.ejs', {
         playersList: playersList,
         world:world
     });
  }  


});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('watcher running');
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a relative path issue in the `<link />` tag. Can you share your `index.ejs` template file? Or try adding a `/` to the start of the `href` attribute of the `<link />` tag linking to the CSS file. So it would be `<link href="/css.css" />`

Comment: thank you! it was that, i knew it was a simple thing, still I don't understand why this happens, isn't supposed to be enough indicating where to find the static files in the middleware? why a change on the dynamic route doesn't work? sorry still pretty new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a relative path issue. Here's an example.

In your initial route setup, using `/:world`, you would have a URL like `example.com/earth`, with a `<link />` tag like `<link href="myCSS.css" />`. In this setup the `<link />` tag is pointing to `example.com/myCSS.css`.

In the 2nd route setup, using `/:world/:page`, you would have a URL like `example.com/earth/about`, with a `<link />` tag like `<link href="myCSS.css" />`. In this setup the `<link />` tag is point to `example.com/earth/myCSS.css`.

This is because the path to the file in the `<link />` tag is relative. Meaning it's relative to the current page's path.

To fix this you need to update the `<link />` to use an absolute path. This can be done two ways:

1. Use an absolute `href` like `http://example.com/myCSS.css`
2. Use an absolute `href` like `/myCSS.css` - with a leading `/`

Either of these methods will cause the browser to look for the CSS file in starting from the root domain. That is, the browser will now look for the CSS file at `example.com/myCSS.css`. Alternative, if we changed it to `<link href="/styles/myCSS.css" />` the browser would look for the CSS file at `example.com/styles/myCSS.css`.